# How can i change screen image when i click the picture on the bottom sheet? //Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, mobile

```
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    print("tabbed");
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                          top: Radius.circular(0)
                        )
                      ),
                      builder: (context) {
                        return GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 3,
                            ),
                            itemCount: theme().avatars.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: (){
                                    Navigator.pop(context, theme().avatars[index]);
                                  },
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      theme().avatars[index],
                                      ),
                                    
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                        );

                      },
                    ).then((selectedOption){
                      if (selectedOption != null) {
                        updateData(selectedOption); // Seçime göre değişiklik yapma işlevini çağırma
                      }
                    });

                  },
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset(
                        defaultAvatar,
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
```

I want when i chose an image on bottom sheet then change seccon clip over

```
child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset(
                        defaultAvatar,
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
```

i used this function but set state method doesnt work when i click an image on bottomsheet.

```
  void updateData(String selectedOption) {
      setState(() {
        defaultAvatar = selectedOption;
      });
      print(defaultAvatar);
      return defaultAvatar;
    }
```

When I click on the bottom page image, I want the photo in the clipover on the main screen to change.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8EWe.png)

Answer (score 0):

But it's working completely fine in my case. Here is the code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var defaultAvatar = 'images/a1.jpg';
  void updateData(String selectedOption) {
    setState(() {
      defaultAvatar = selectedOption;
    });
  }

  var avatars = [
    'images/a1.jpg',
    'images/a2.png',
    'images/a3.jpg',
    'images/a4.png',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        title: Text("Hello"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("tabbed");
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(0))),
                builder: (context) {
                  return GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                      ),
                      itemCount: avatars.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context, avatars[index]);
                            },
                            child: ClipOval(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                avatars[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ).then((selectedOption) {
                if (selectedOption != null) {
                  updateData(
                      selectedOption); // Seçime göre değişiklik yapma işlevini çağırma
                }
              });
            },
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Image.asset(defaultAvatar,
                  width: 150, height: 150, fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but didnt work. I dont understand how is possible.  ty for answer.

Comment: Try printing out selectedOption and check the value if it's correct or not.

Comment: when i try printing selectedOptions and i see output in terminal. Function is working but photo doesnt change. I get the same result when I try using provider

Comment: If you have GitHub link of your code share it with me.

Comment: https://github.com/mk-ozturk/math_app.git   coding can be a bit confusing, i'm just trying to improve myself.

Comment: And have u any advice please tell me. I need the experience of professionals like you. Ty.

Comment: i fixed it. When i try to write with provider package then working it. Ty for helping mate.

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment. Anyways good to hear that you solved it. Keep fluttering.